# javascript get only array elements equal to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to compare the variable determineHour against the array stationRentalsHours, whenever the variable would be equal to a stationRentalsHours element, I'd like to add that element to another Array (stationRentalsHoursTemp), but only the values that match. I tried with simple operators, but that doesn't put anything into the temp array. I also tried using JQuery $.inArray, but that gives me some strange results, Equal to those in the original array. Are there any other methods of comparing a variable with an array for this particular task?

Thank you for any help.

```
function updateChart() {
    if(canvas3){canvas3.destroy();}

    var determineHour = selectNumber.options[selectNumber.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    for (var i = 0; i < stationRentalsHours.length; i++) {
        /*if(determineHour == stationRentalsHours){
        stationRentalsHoursTemp.push(stationRentalsHours[i]);*/
        if( $.inArray(determineHour, stationRentalsHours[i])){
        stationRentalsHoursTemp.push(stationRentalsHours[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, instead of using $.inArray, you can simply use the for loop and the index to test the equality.  I guess you mixed up two things:

```
var determineHour = selectNumber.options[selectNumber.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
for (var i = 0; i < stationRentalsHours.length; i++) {
    if( determineHour == stationRentalsHours[i]){
        stationRentalsHoursTemp.push(stationRentalsHours[i]);
    }
}
```

Better yet, use filter:

```
var determineHour = selectNumber.options[selectNumber.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
stationRentalsHoursTemp = stationRentalsHours.filter(function(val){return val == determineHour;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`if( $.inArray(determineHour, stationRentalsHours[i])){`

Try

`if( $.inArray(determineHour, stationRentalsHours) != -1){`

Answer (score 0):

Your commented out code would do the trick with a slight amendment to the `if` condition.  Your original condition was comparing a string to an array instead of an individual element in that array:

```
function updateChart() {
  if(canvas3){
    canvas3.destroy();
  }
  var determineHour = selectNumber.options[selectNumber.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  for (var i = 0; i < stationRentalsHours.length; i++){
    if(determineHour == stationRentalsHours[i]){
       stationRentalsHoursTemp.push(stationRentalsHours[i]);
    }
  }
}
```